# how to normalize rating in scale of 1 to 5?

Tags: rating, normalize

In Yahoo! Movie dataset the rating scale is from 1 to 13. here, 1 represent good rating and 13 represent the lowest rating to the movie.
if there is 0 then it represents that user didn't rate that movie.

```
rating { 13 12 11 10 9 8  7  6 5  4  3 2  1 0} OR 
rating { A+ A  A- B+ B B- C+ C C- C+ D D- F 0}

eg. user m1 m2 m3
     1    2  3 13
     2    0  1  7
```

but I don't know how to normalize rating in the scale of 1 to 13 into a scale of 1 to 5.
simply I can do one thing i.e.

```
{A+,A,A-} = 5
{B+,B,B-} = 4
{C+,C,C-} = 3
{D+,D,D-} = 2
{F}       = 1
```

is there any other method or by using any formula ?

Answer (score 0):

If floating points are allowed, simply multiply with 5/13. Round to full numbers if necessary.

If 5 is the best, substract the result from 6 (handle 0 with an if clause)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
No sir, floating value is not allowed. at the time of comparison, it will create bugs.

Comment: Then you should round at runtime or define an array calculated manually, e.g.:
[0,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]

Unfortunately, not all values in 1..5 can be mapped to from the same number of values in 1..13. This cannot be changed since 13 is not a multiple of 5

Simply normalize by accessing the array with the old score as the index.